# Code exits for no apparent reason with no error message while using True and False statements to switch from one loop to another

Tags: python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

So I was just working on a tic tac toe offline game where it uses True and False statements to switch from Player 1 to Player 2. A list keeps track of how many tiles are left as strings ("tile 1"," tile 2", etc). So what I did was keep `player1turn = True` before the game began and then after Player 1 chooses a tile, `player1turn = False`. If player 1 chooses Tile 1, then tile 1 is removed from the list. But when I run the code, Player 1 can do his move, and player 2 can only do it once because after that the code exits with no error message. My Pycharm IDE is also not telling me about any errors that could have caused this bug. My full script:

```
'''
Name : Tic Tac Toe
Purpose : A Simple Tic Tac Toe Game With 1 friend
Plan : Make the board with | and. and _
        Mark each box from 1-9
        Ask the user for input.
        Anything more than 9 or less than 1 will result in a message "Too Big" or "Too Small" and won't restart the game
        A tile already taken will result in a message"Already Taken" and won't restart the game.
        If possible, X or O option will be there.
'''

print("Welcome to the tic tac toe offline made by Command Blocks!")

print("Player 1 will play first as X")
print("Player 2 will play second as O")
player1turn = True
r1 = 1
r2 = 2
r3 = 3
r4 = 4
r5 = 5
r6 = 6
r7 = 7
r8 = 8
r9 = 9

def board():
    print("._______._______._______.\n|  ", r1, "  |  ", r2, "  |  ", r3, "  |\n|       |       |       |")
    print("._______._______._______.\n|  ", r4, "  |  ", r5, "  |  ", r6, "  |\n|       |       |       |")
    print("._______._______._______.\n|  ", r7, "  |  ", r8, "  |  ", r9, "  |\n|       |       |       |\n._______._______._______.")


a_p = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
board()
print("available places are:",a_p)
while a_p != [] and player1turn == True:
        y_m = input( "Player 1 please enter your input:\n")
        try:
            if y_m == "1":
                a_p.remove("1")
                r1 = "X"
                board()
                print("available places are:", a_p)
                player1turn = False


            elif y_m == "2":
                a_p.remove("2")
                r2 = "X"
                board()
                print("available places are:", a_p)
                player1turn = False

            elif y_m == "3":
                a_p.remove("3")
                r3 = "X"
                board()
                print("available places are:", a_p)
                player1turn = False

            elif y_m == "4":
                a_p.remove("4")
                r4 = "X"
                board()
                print("available places are:", a_p)
                player1turn = False

            elif y_m == "5":
                a_p.remove("5")
                r5 = "X"
                board()
                print("available places are:", a_p)
                player1turn = False

            elif y_m == "6":
                a_p.remove("6")
                r6 = "X"
                board()
                print("available places are:", a_p)
                player1turn = False

            elif y_m == "7":
                a_p.remove("7")
                r7 = "X"
                board()
                print("available places are:", a_p)
                player1turn = False

            elif y_m == "8":
                a_p.remove("8")
                r8 = "X"
                board()
                print("available places are", a_p)
                player1turn = False

            elif y_m == "9":
                a_p.remove("9")
                r9 = "X"
                board()
                print("available places are", a_p)
                player1turn = False

            else:
                print("Please enter a number from 1-9")



        except ValueError:
            print("That spot is already taken !")

while a_p != [] and player1turn == False:
        y_m = input( "Player 2 please enter your input:\n")
        try:
            if y_m == "1":
                a_p.remove("1")
                r1 = "O"
                board()
                print("available places are:", a_p)
                player1turn = True


            elif y_m == "2":
                a_p.remove("2")
                r2 = "O"
                board()
                print("available places are:", a_p)
                player1turn = True

            elif y_m == "3":
                a_p.remove("3")
                r3 = "O"
                board()
                print("available places are:", a_p)
                player1turn = True

            elif y_m == "4":
                a_p.remove("4")
                r4 = "O"
                board()
                print("available places are:", a_p)
                player1turn = True

            elif y_m == "5":
                a_p.remove("5")
                r5 = "O"
                board()
                print("available places are:", a_p)
                player1turn = True

            elif y_m == "6":
                a_p.remove("6")
                r6 = "O"
                board()
                print("available places are:", a_p)
                player1turn = True

            elif y_m == "7":
                a_p.remove("7")
                r7 = "O"
                board()
                print("available places are:", a_p)
                player1turn = True

            elif y_m == "8":
                a_p.remove("8")
                r8 = "O"
                board()
                print("available places are:", a_p)
                player1turn = True

            elif y_m == "9":
                a_p.remove("9")
                r9 = "O"
                board()
                print("available places are:", a_p)
                player1turn = True

            else:
                print("Please enter a number from 1-9")



        except ValueError:
            print("That spot is already taken !")
print("Won")
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you would rewrite the code exactly, but after you set Player1Turn back to "True" you need to loop back to the top of the code.  You might possibly code the "action" section as a function and just call the function over and over until a win or loss (or a cat's game) is achieved.

Comment: @Don'FreihEitner'Eitner when I put the entire thing in a function, The code needs the value of player1turn after the `def` statement, causing the error `line 39, in game_start
    while a_p != [] and player1turn == True:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'player1turn' referenced before assignment` however, If I put player1turn = True inside the def, It never goes to player 2